# Alphabetical ordering in BFS

Tags: breadth-first-search, alphabetical

I have troubles differentiating between BFS with alphabetical ordering and BFS without it.

For example, to find a spanning tree in this graph (starting from E).

[Starting G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk3HS.png)

After adding {E,B} and {E,C}

[T after added EB and EC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f5fU.png)

I'm not sure whether to continue adding {B,F} or {C,F}.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether to continue adding {B,F} or {C,F}. Thank you very
>   much.

Well, the answer depends on the order in which you add the vertices *B* and *C* in your queue of [**BFS**](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/tutorial/) algorithm. If you look at the algorithm:

```
BFS (G, s)      //Where G is the graph and s is the Source Node

  let Q be queue.
  Q.enqueue( s ) //Inserting s in queue until all its neighbour vertices are marked.

  mark s as visited.
  while ( Q is not empty)
       //Removing that vertex from queue,whose neighbour will be visited now
       v  =  Q.dequeue( )

      //processing all the neighbours of v  
      for all neighbours w of v in Graph G
           if w is not visited 
                Q.enqueue( w ) //Stores w in Q to further visit its neighbours                       

      mark w as visited.
```

Its clear that it **does not specify** what should be the **order** in which you enque the neighbours of a vertex.

So if you visit the neighbours of *E* in the order: *B* , *C* , then clearly due to **FIFO** property of Queue data structure, node *B* will be dequed(taken out of queue) before *C* and you will have the edge *B--F*. If the order is *C* , *B*, then the edge would be *C--F* for similar reasons.

Once you understand the pseudocode, you will understand it very clearly.